# PowerShell Cannot Find Service When Run Through Task Scheduler

Tags: powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I have a PowerShell script that restarts a service that is passed to it as an argument. This script is running on a server that I am logging in to remotely, and it is running as a different user. I need this script to run as a scheduled task, but I cannot make it work when it runs via Task Scheduler.

Here is the code of the PowerShell script

```
Start-Transcript -Path "C:\scripts\restart-services-log.txt" -append

$numArgs = $args.Length
"$numArgs arguments submitted."
" "

if ($numArgs -le 0) {
 "No services passed in to restart"
} else {
 foreach ($serviceName in $args) {
 try {
  $service = Get-Service $serviceName
  $service.Refresh()
    
  "$serviceName ..."
  "$serviceName is " + $service.status
  " "
  if ($service.status -eq "Stopped") {
   try {
    "    $serviceName is not running, starting ..."
    Start-Service -name $serviceName
    $service.Refresh()
    "    $serviceName is " + $service.status
   }
   catch {
    "Exception starting $($serviceName): $_"
   }
  } else {
   try {
    "    Stopping $serviceName ..."
    Stop-Service -name $serviceName
    $service.Refresh()
    "    $serviceName is " + $service.status
   }
   catch {
    "Exception stopping $($serviceName): $_"
   }
   " "
   try {
    "    Starting $serviceName ..."
    Start-Service -name $serviceName
    $service.Refresh()
    "    $serviceName is " + $service.status
   }
   catch {
    "Exception starting $($serviceName): $_"
   }
  }
  " "
  }
  catch {
   "Exception: $_"
  }
 }
}

"Done."

Stop-Transcript
```

When I run the PowerShell script as myself, it works fine and the service is restarted. It would not, however, run via the Task Scheduler as this user.

Based on another post from this site, I have created a batch file that runs the PowerShell script and funnels stdio and stderr into a text file to see what is happening. When I run this batch file as the user we use in Task Scheduler, it runs successfully and identically to how it runs when I run it as myself.

When I try and run it via Task Scheduler, however, I get the error "Get-Service : Cannot find any service with service name 'MyServiceName'." (where 'MyServiceName' is a substitute for the service name I am passing it)

I have set up the scheduled task to run as the user. It is set to run whether the user is logged on or not, the 'Do not store password' box is not selected, and the 'Run with highest privileges' box is selected.

The action of the scheduled task is to start a program (it just runs the .bat file) and I have it set to start in the directory that the batch file exists in (because I have to specify something there so that it can make the log text file)

The user account that the scheduled task is set to run as is an administrator account, and has 'Log on as a batch job' and 'Log on as a service' permissions under the Local Security Policy.

If anyone has any ideas about what to try next, that would be very welcome.

**Edit 1:**

I have now also tried the following things:

I saw a post that suggested that maybe Task Scheduler was trying to run 32-bit PowerShell on a 64-bit system, and that I should use the following code to prevent that from happening

```
#############################################################################
#If Powershell is running the 32-bit version on a 64-bit machine, we 
#need to force powershell to run in 64-bit mode .
#############################################################################
if ($env:PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 -eq "AMD64") {
    write-warning "Y'arg Matey, we're off to 64-bit land....."
    if ($myInvocation.Line) {
        &"$env:WINDIR\sysnative\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NonInteractive -NoProfile $myInvocation.Line
    }else{
        &"$env:WINDIR\sysnative\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NonInteractive -NoProfile -file "$($myInvocation.InvocationName)" $args
    }
exit $lastexitcode
}
```

I have tried this code, and nothing has changed (based on the comment, the code is not actually executing, so I think that the initial hypothesis here was wrong)

My .bat file uses the following code

```
@echo off
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass "C:\scripts\restart-services.ps1" "MyServiceName" > scriptlogfile.txt 2>&1
```

The inclusion of '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass' is also not fixing the problem

Comment: Task manager only shows system and current user processes.  You need to run as an admin to get all users processes.  You need to Start-Process as an Admin and then set the -Credential to the current user.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.3

Comment: Task Manger shows processes of all users for me

Comment: Are you passing the parameters correctly in task scheduler? All arguments including the path to the powershell script must be included in the second box in the action tab. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: The File parameter can't support scripts using a parameter that expects an array of argument values. This, unfortunately, is a limitation of how a native command gets argument values. When you call a native executable (such as powershell or pwsh), it doesn't know what to do with an array, so it's passed as a string.

Comment: Try filling in the fields: **Program/script** `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`, **Add arguments (optional)** `-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "restart-services.ps1" -args "MyServiceName"`, **Start in (optional)** `C:\scripts`

Comment: I've solved it with the help of someone from the place I work. It was a combination of a learning disability and poorly named accounts

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that, even though I thought the user I was running the job as was a full administrator, it was not. The machine in question has two accounts where the username is different by only one character, and I have a hard time differentiating between certain letters in certain fonts.

So it turns out I'm very silly, but someone from within my organisation who is better at reading than I am was able to help me in the end. We made the correct account an administrator, and that was that.